# Why exception is caught 3 times?

Tags: java, exception, log4j2

I am catching `FileNotFoundException` and logging it to file via log4j2. The log statement is invoked thrice. I replaced log statement with sysout statement to check if this printed a message 3 times. It did print to console 3 times. Why is the sysout statement or the log statement invoked 3 times?
Below is the code snippet.

```
prop = new Properties();
String path ="invalid path";
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    log.error("FileInputStream exception");
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

Comment: You're probably calling your method three times.

Comment: If you run in standalone mode, do you get 3 times, if not, then somewhere the function may be getting called 3 times.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Set your IDE in debug mode and check if it is being called 3 times

Comment: And yes, the logical conclusion is: that catch block is triggered three times, which makes it likely that the code around it is called three times, too!

Comment: @frewper Not *if*. _and check *why* it is being called 3 times_

Comment: And hint: instead of doing just a println("Exception") you could print the whole stack trace. The stack trace tells you exactly which call stack lead you to this situation. In other words: you have all the information you need to identify the paths to that code already in these call stacks. So dont throw them away, but print  or log them, and then read what is going on.

Comment: With little knowledge about stack trace I could  figure out that this is due to TestNG framework, ITestListener and the sequence objects are created. Need to understand the working of TestNG framework. Thanks anyways

Comment: You should also check your `log4j2.xml`-configuration, there might be three appenders referencing `System.out`/`System.err`. If your `System.out.println("Exception");` only prints one `Exception` on console but `log4j2` is logging trice, then the signs point to misconfiguration.

Comment: I am not sure what needs to be done with this question. This question shouldn't be posted at first place. The root cause of the problem was that 3 class inherited a Base class and a method in the Base class constructor was invoked thrice. Moving this "init" method out solved the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question shouldn't be posted at first place. The root cause of the problem was that 3 class inherited a Base class and a method in the Base class constructor was invoked thrice. Moving this "init" method out solved the problem.